# Osmosis and hydrostatic pressure

Tags: physiology, membrane-transport, blood-pressure

I'm confused about the role of hydrostatic pressure compared to osmotic pressure.

Q1:If I have a U-tube with a membrane permeable only to water molecules and equal volumes of water on either side but only 1 side (side B) has NaCl, the osmotic pressure would cause water to move from side A to side B,correct ?

Q2.But then hydrostatic pressure would cause water to move back to side A.
So, the water would move from side A to side B until the effect caused by the hydrostatic pressure = effect caused by osmotic pressure ?

Q3. The last statement wouldn't be correct If I said that "water moves until the hydrostatic pressure=osmotic pressure" would it ?

and lastly, My friend said the water would move until the hydrostatic pressure on both sides was equal 
Q4. If water is moving from side A to side B then the we have more water molecules at side B, how would side A ever reach the hydrostatic pressure at side B ?
Do I have a misunderstanding in the concept of hydrostatic pressure ? In this context, I understand that it is the pressure exerted by the water molecules on the selectively permeable membrane.

The more I google hydrostatic pressure the more lost I get because all sources seem to explain in terms of equations and physics and I'm only taking this for an introductory course in physiology.

Comment: Do the answers at https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/89609/osmotic-pressure help you?

Comment: I understand everything thats written in that page, I think of osmotic pressure  as a vacuum too but I might have a misunderstanding in hydrostatic pressure and what equals what at equilibrium